# Suddenly a new mounted volume appears, how to remove it

Tags: mount, snap

I have previously installed phpstorm using snap. And later removed it using:

```
sudo snap remove phpstorm
```

But still there is a 425 MB mount volume on the system. What can I do to it? PHPstorm is already uninstalled. It looks like this:

[image]

I am new to ubuntu so could not find a way to deal with it.

Comment: In the top bar of Disks you can see  a minus icon `[-]` next to the title, use it and that may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your screenshot it is clearly shown that this filesystem is mounted on a file that has been already deleted. Probably uninstalltion of phpstorm for some reason did not unmount the snap before deleting the snap file. After you reboot the system everything should be resolved.